# Database Design: accessing populated table becomes slow due to computation

Tags: database, database-design, firebird

I have a Firebird database, which let's say has Tables A and B which look like this:

TableA

```
TableB's Id | SomeNumber | OtherNumber | ComputedByField              | OtherIntField
    1              5          200           SomeNumber*OtherNumber          10
    1              2          70                  ...                       20
```

TableB

```
Id   | Sum                     |  Sum
 1     Sum of OtherIntFIeld       Sum of ComputedByField

where TableA'sId = TableB's Id
```

But now that TableB is getting populated (it's at 2k rows) accessing it becomes also slow due to that computation.

So my question is : Should I drop TableA's `computedby` field and add it straight into TableB, and when new TableA rows are added to modify the Corresponding row manually? (This should be faster, but I don't really like it)

Edit: The performance issue comes from the fact that there are two `computedby` fields which do exactly the same query over TableA but return different fields. I guess that is the part which needs optimization.

Edit2: The rows are computed as follows

```
TABLEB_FIELD_X COMPUTED BY ((
    select SUM(TableA.FieldX) from TableA
    where TableA.FAT_ID = TableB.ID
))

TABLEB_FIELD_Y COMPUTED BY ((
    select SUM(TableA.FieldY) from TableA
    where TableA.FAT_ID = TableB.ID
))
```

The main issue I believe comes from the fact these two independent fields query the same rows from TableA they just get a different field as result.

Comment: This is an ill posed question because it lacks important details. For example, how do you calculated the sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `TableB`, why don't you create a [view](http://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-ddl-view.html)? (**Warning:** I never used Firebird and I don't know how well it supports views).

Such view will be something like:

```
 create view Totals (SumX, SumY)
          as
      select SUM(FieldX), SUM(FieldY)
        from TableA
    group by ID
```

Every time `TableA` will be changed, such view (`Totals`) will be updated automatically.
A decent DBMS will do a good job at optimizing this: it will recalculate *enough* of `Totals` only when `TableA` is changed, unlike your `TableB`, which will be recalculated every time is queried (I presume by your performance problems - to be sure one needs to know Firebird internals).

`Totals` will be like any other table (but read-only); you will filter information with something like:

```
select * from Totals where ID = ...
```

**P.S.:** Walter Mitty brought to my attention in comments below what I assumed about your original solution, i.e. that `TableA`:

- must be in (at least) First Normal Form (1NF) - otherwise one does not have guaranteed correct results for relational operations (**nota bene:** one must know your application requirements and conceptual/logical design in detail - which is impractical to acquire in a forum/via indirect communication - to spot eventual problems in a not completely normalized design, such us insert/delete/update anomalies; a **good** book on DB theory will spare you headaches and unfortunately such books are few);
- it is properly indexed (at least on ID).

It is unfortunate that SQL-based DBMSes **require** such physical design details from users to have decent performances, it is contrary to what a DBMS is supposed to be good at (it has all the information needed to do a good job automatically, i.e. ownership of physical data structures and data access path statistics).

Comment: The view will have to get an ID as a parameter for which rows to filter

Comment: I don't understand. Such view will be exactly like any other table (but read-only).

Comment: You are welcome. Test it, I think it will be much more efficient - optimizations are the job of a DBMS, but you need to use it correctly. What about reading a good book on DB theory?

Comment: Yeah, I'll be getting one soon

Comment: I suggest "SQL and Relational Theory - How to Write Accurate SQL Code" by Chris J. Date.

Comment: MaD70, you gave the right answer.  But it might be worth pointing out that Table A is not necessarily in 1NF, and asking what indexes there are on TableA.  If there are no indexes, that would explain while its bogging down at only 2K rows.

Comment: Right: it is always difficult to give the right advice without knowing much about requirements and conceptual/logic design.
w.r.t. indexes, you are right again, but I forgot to mention indexes because I presumed he indexed TableA properly.
Anyway, I hate that SQL-based DBMSes **require** such physical design details to have decent performances. It is contrary to what a DBMS is supposed to be good at, i.e. relieve users from physical design considerations. I will update my answer mentioning indexes.

Comment: Both Tables are in 2nf by the way

Answer (score 0):

I would use a trigger on Table A which updates table B with the sum of the fields after any inserts/updates/deletes in Table A.

This would have a small additional impact on any transactions happening on table A, but would be more efficient when querying Table B.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would you want to recalculate the whole table each time you update? That's what your code and explanation seem to imply.

The best thing is to store computed value as a regular value integer or whatever is the result. Then you can also add things like indexing and such. If you leave it as a dynamic field your index will also have to be rebuild on the fly if you have one.

The standard procedure is to move this to code, and calculate & update ComputedValue field on the fly when you update either of the other two. And if you have more than a one place in your code where you update that field I would look at optimizing your code.

Also if you REALLY REALLY need to speed it up you can resort to stored procedures ( I don't use Firebird - so I don't know if it supports it) and call them from your code when you need to.